# Assign value by location in xml

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I have xml data, `XMLData`, and something like this:

```
<cfset TransactionInformation = 
[
    {    
         VariableName = "someData", 
         XMLLocation="HX5.HTML_Reports.HTML_Report.XMLText", 
         Value="" 
    }
]/>
```

I'm trying to do the following:

```
<cfloop array="#TransactionInformation#" index="Field" >
    <cftry>
           <cfset Field['Value'] = "#XMLData[Field['XMLLocation'] ]#" /> 
    <cfcatch>
        <!--- some error catching --->
    </cfcatch>
    <cftry>
</cfloop>
```

This throws an error, `#XMLData[Field['XMLLocation'] ]#` I don't think is the right syntax to do this. Can this be done and how?

The error

`Element HX5.HTML_Reports.HTML_Report.XMLText is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.xml.XmlNodeList.`